# Bash prompt "variables" not working?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, prompt

I have added this into my ~/.bashrc, to change the prompt:

`PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '`

However, it is not showing what I want. I believe this is meant to show my username and possibly the directory that I am in, however it is just showing `[\u@\h \w]\$` in the terminal.

Even having it at just `PS1='\u'` still shows `\u` in the terminal.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're using bash?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Just realised if I run the command `bash` in the terminal then it starts working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely running a different shell, not `bash`.

In your shell, run the command `bash`.  If the prompt now resolves correctly, change your shell to `/bin/bash` using `chsh` or `usermod`.

Comment: How do I make it so it automatically goes to bash when I open a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using pure shell instead of bash. To solve it find the line
including your username within /etc/passwd via

```
grep -w '^YOURUSERNAME' /etc/passwd
```

Then edit it with Sudo permission with a command like

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

and change the end of the line from "sh" to "bash". You will end with a similar line as below:

> YOURUSERNAME:x:1001:1001::/home/YOURUSERNAME:/bin/bash

Then either rerun the service or relogin to have access to the bash features. Have fun